# Using I hope in professional environment

Tags: phrases, expressions

I need to state that my goal is to answer some answers.  Starting my e-mail with the "I hope..."  does not sound professional.  Any alternatives you can provide me with?

Comment: Answer some answers? Do you mean to get some answers to questions?

Comment: I hope you will forgive me for suggesting that your basic premise is flawed. There's nothing "unprofessional" about expressing one's hopes - regardless of whether they're genuinely heartfelt, or simply a stylistic cliche.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I **forecast** blah blah blah.

> predict or estimate (a future event or trend).

Comment: I can't begin to imagine what kind of "professional" email could possibly start with the words *"I forecast..."* (unless you were a professional weather forecaster! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I forecast that our Q4 budget will be 3 million dollars, so we will do XYZ.

Comment: I think you've illustrated one problem with the usage in that very example - in a professional context, it would be *"**We** forecast"*. Not that it's very professional to forecast *budgets*. The professionals are supposed to ***know*** what their budgets are/will be - they ***forecast*** things like turnover and profits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I work in the ultra-corporate global Dilbert world.  I just did a search of all mail items in my outlook for "I forecast"... 273 different email chains.  This is about 20K emails covering 10 years.  I forecast in this sense is forecasting to your group when you don't know what the real forecast will be - based on levels above you.  Definitely used, right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're writing a letter to ask for some information, in which case you want to be very polite without going too far off the deep end ("I humbly beseech of you").

Something such as "I would be grateful if you could..", "It would be of great help if you could..", "I wonder if you'd mind if I asked.." could work, depending on the relationship of the supplicant (that's you) to the person being petitioned.

Answer (score 0):

**I intend to...**

**I will attempt to...**

**My goal is to...**

Just some other suggestions...